# Cannot click button selenium Iframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to get the next page button from this site "https://remoters.io/?s=finance..I have tried switching the iframe which I think is the right iframe..still no luck. I have tried finding this button with `find_element_by_xpath` etc.

```
next_iframe = driver.switch_to_frame('aswift_2')
next = next_iframe.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Next')
```

Can anyone have a look and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I go to "https://remoters.io/?s=finance" I do not see an iframe. I can get to the second page with the code below. `time.sleep(5)` can be removed if you write some extra code to make sure the modal is gone before trying to click next.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://remoters.io/?s=finance")

agree = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"AGREE")]')))
agree.click()

next = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(),"Next")]')))
while "page/2/" not in driver.current_url:
    next.click()
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping to avoid that..Is it necessary to use Wait?..I think the button loads with the page..It's not something..that loads after..can you have a look?

Comment: @Abhishek Rai "Wait" makes the scrip more stable incase the website loads slow which happens eventually.  Updated the answer to handle the issue I saw where the popup modal fading from view would cause the script to finish without getting to the second page.

Comment: Unfortunately My PC got the blue screen of death. No way for me to check...:(..

Answer (score 0):

using the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://remoters.io/?s=finance')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('next').click()
```

I can click to the next page.

#### Explanation

In order to find out how to select a specific element I use `ScrapeMate Beta` on Firefox, which gives me the higher level classes directly. Another option is to use `inspect element`:

[image]

Now we can see the following:

1. It is a link, but there are multiple 'a' elements.
2. It is stored under the 'page-numbers' class. But this one is also not specific enough (can use `find_elements` and then filter over the text input)
3. The class name `next`, which is a unique class on this page, so I picked that value.

Try to keep full path searches to the bare minimum, they are relatively slow.